# Start over with django migrations

Tags: python, django, database-migration

I have 2 related questions.

1. I have deleted all my migrations, including the migrations directory, from all the apps in my project. I've started with a clean database. But still, when I run `./manage.py makemigrations`, django says there are no changes to be made. How do I completely start over with migrations? No squashing, just starting over.
2. It seems that when I call `makemigrations`, django consults the database. I'd like my codebase to be the only source of truth for my migrations. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If an app doesn't have a `migrations/` directory with an `__init__.py` file (even on Python 3), Django won't create any migrations if you don't specify the app name. You either have to create the directories and `__init__.py` files, or you have to call `./manage.py makemigrations <app_name>` for each app, which forces Django to create the directory.
2. It doesn't. It may connect to the database during the `makemigrations` command, but the migrations are purely based on your models.

Comment: The migrations are purely based on the models ... and on whatever happens to be stored in the database, related to migrations. The `makemigrations` command, which is the one storing the migrations in your codebase, wants to connect to the database.